# django template language not working

Tags: django

```
#base.html
<html>
<head><title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

#child.html
{% extends base.html %}
{% block content}
    This is the content that
    comes here
{% endblock %}
```

but the html output of base.html not displaying content.? Why this template language not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template inheritance includes the parent template in the child, not the other way around.

Render `child.html` and you'll see your content surrounded by the `base.html` (parent) markup.

Also, you need to quote the parent template name:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    Content!
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If i render child.html the error is `Invalid block tag: 'endblock'`

Comment: Because you have `{% block content }` and you need `{% block content %}`